# Team Foundation Server: How to view changeset history

Tags: tfs

I'd like to know how to view entire changeset history in Team Foundation Server for a given project.

this is what I want to see-
starting from changeset 1 all the way to the current changeset:

show me change #, username, date of submission, description, files that were changed, etc.

note: i don't want to just see the history for a given file, or dir, i want to see the history for the whole darn thing. i.e., what happened in changeset 1, what happened in changeset 2, what happened in changeset 3, etc.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

you can go to the [`Source Control Explorer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181370.aspx) in Visual Studio and right-click on your project and select [`View History`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181413.aspx).  This will show you the list of all changesets made to that project, who made them, the date they were made and any comment added to those changesets.  if you double-click on any particular changeset, you can see the files that were changed in that one changeset.

edited to add links.

Comment: No that only shows who made the changes to that particular file. For example if you right click the solution, it'll just tell you who made changes to that particular .sln file. If you right click project it'll take you who made changes to that particular.csproj file

Comment: @foreyez yes but if you right-click the entire source control folder (which you have previously mapped in your Workspace), you will see all the changes made to all the files in that folder, which is what you asked for.

Comment: I think you were confusing that, like I was at first, with Solution Explorer.  This only works in Source Control Explorer.  I'm not sure why they wanted to have different behavior, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 11):

This can also be done via the command line.

Be advised that if you have a significant change history in that path, this process can take a long time, and (at least under TFS 2008) can eat up a lot of tempDB space on your data tier.

```
tf history "$/TeamProject/Path" /recursive /noprompt /format:detailed
```

This will dump the entire change history for a given folder, including what was included in the check-in.

Answer (score 7):

In Source Control Explorer (there is a button "[Find Changesets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181408.aspx)" in toolbar), or via menu: **File -> Source Control -> Find -> Find Changesets**. The Find Changesets dialog box appears.

You could use it to see all changesets by user or by all users, etc..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution (tested in Visual Studio 2017):**

1. Go to **View** (in top menu bar) -> **Team Explorer**
2. In the newly opened Team explorer go to **Home** (the gray house) -> **Source Control Explorer**
3. **Right click on the topmost element of the folders** (your TFS-Server) -> **View History**

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to check with the browser.

Open browser and sign in TFS, and follow the path below:

1. Choose your collection or organization
2. Choose your project
3. From the top menu, click on the "Code", then "Files" or Click "Repos" from the menu on the left then "Files"

Here you can see the list of all files and click on each one, and click on "History" tab on the right, to see the changes.